# File format or file extension is not valid, Verify that the file is not corrupted - python

Tags: python, web-scraping, special-characters, xlsx, file-writing

**Problem:**

- I've written a code that first creates a file and saves the data to the
  same file.
- After opening the file an error shows up File Format or file extension is
  not valid, Verify that the file is not corrupted.

**Code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import datetime as dt
import csv
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='C://Downloads//webdrivers//geckodriver.exe')


c1 = 'amazon_data_' + dt.datetime.now().strftime("%d_%b_%y_%I_%M_%p")

# d = open(str(c1) + '.csv', 'x', encoding='utf-8')
d = open(str(c1) + '.xlsx', 'x', encoding='utf-8')

for c in range(1):

    a = f'https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=sony+headphones&as=on&as-show=on&otracker=AS_Query_HistoryAutoSuggest_1_4_na_na_na&otracker1=AS_Query_HistoryAutoSuggest_1_4_na_na_na&as-pos=1&as-type=HISTORY&suggestionId=sony+headphones&requestId=ad797917-16ae-401e-98df-1c79a43d40c3&as-backfill=on&page={c}'

    '''
    request_response = requests.head(a)

    status_code = request_response.status_code
    if status_code == 200:
        print(True)

    else:
        print(False)
        '''
    driver.get(a)

    # time.sleep(1)

    page_soup = Soup(urlopen(a), 'html5lib')

    container = page_soup.find_all('div', {'class': '_4ddWXP'})
    for containers in container:
        find_url = containers.find('a')['href']
        new_url = 'https://www.flipkart.com' + find_url

        fetch = driver.get(new_url)
        # time.sleep(1)
        page_source = driver.page_source
        page_soup = Soup(page_source, 'html.parser')
        for data in page_soup:

            try:
                product_name = data.find('span', {'class': 'B_NuCI'}).text.strip()
                price = data.find('div', {'class': "_30jeq3 _16Jk6d"}).text.strip()
                current_url = new_url
            except:
                print('Not Available')
            # print(product_name, '\n', price, '\n', current_url, '\n')
            d.write(product_name + price + current_url + '\n')
```

**Error I got**

1. While trying to save the output data in .xlsx format, It saves the file properly. But while opening it, an error pops out:- The file format of the extension is not valid, verify the file is not corrupted and the file extension matches the format of the file.

**Things I tried**

When I try to write the output data with .csv it saves properly. But while opening the file, data has some special characters and data is not written in single cell.

** Output of single cell while writing data through .csv method **

```
JBL a noise cancellation enabled Bluetooth~
```

**Uploading an  Image for better Understanding**

- Below I'm providing url of an image which has excel output that I got
  while fetching data from above script and saving it to .csv file.

**Things I want**

1. I want to save this date in .xlsx format with relevant following 3
   headers :- product_name, price, URL.
2. I want all the special characters to be removed so that I get the clean output while writing the data in .xlsx format.

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).

Comment: better use module `csv` or `pandas` to save it - don't format it on your own. Data may need `" "` to create correct column - and `csv` should do it correctly.

Comment: you can't create `xlsx` using `open()` and `write()`. Changing extension from `cvs` to `xlsx` can't create excel file. You have to use special modules to create it correctly - because it has to create XML file compressed as ZIP. Maybe first create normal list with rows of data, next convert to `pandas.DataFrame` and next use `to_csv` to `to.excel`

Comment: `range(1):` makes no sense - it will run it only once so you can run it without `for`-loop.

Comment: @furas - The reason why I wrote range(1) is because i want this code to run for only first 40 products. And when i write 4 then I'll get data of 4 pages that is 40*4 = 160 products

Comment: You should probably read the Python documentation about text encoding.

Comment: can anyone tell me what should i do to improve reputation for this post?

Comment: it is too late to improve reputation. I didn't downvote it so I can remove it. There is so many new questions every hour so nobody will see this question again.

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what you really have in variables when you save data in file. special characters may means that data is in one encoding but you save it with different encoding, or you open it with different encoding. If you write data with encodign `utf-8` then you have to check if you open it also with `utf-8`. If you run code on Windows then sometimes it may uses `CP1250` or `Latin1` instead of `UTF-8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see few problems:

1. using `open()`, `write()` you can't create `xlsx` because it has to be file `.xml` compressed with `zip`
2. some data has `,` which normally is used as separator for columns and you should put data in `" "` to create columns correctly. Better use module `csv` or `pandas` and it will use `" "` automatically. And this can be your main problem.
3. you mix `selenium` with `beautifulsoup` and sometimes you make mess.
4. you use `for data in page_soup` so you get all children on page and run the same code for these elements but you should get values directly from `page_soup`

I would put all data on list - every item as sublist - and later I would convert it to `pandas.DataFrame` and save it using `to_csv()` or `to_excel()`

I would even use `selenium` to search element (ie. `find_elements_by_xpath`) instead of `beautifulsoup` but I skiped this idea in code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

# - before loop -

all_rows = []

#driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='C:\\Downloads\\webdrivers\\geckodriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox()  # I have `geckodriver` in folder `/home/furas/bin` and I don't have to set `executable_path`

# - loop - 

for page in range(1):  # range(10)`
    print('--- page:', page, '---')
    
    url = f'https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=sony+headphones&as=on&as-show=on&otracker=AS_Query_HistoryAutoSuggest_1_4_na_na_na&otracker1=AS_Query_HistoryAutoSuggest_1_4_na_na_na&as-pos=1&as-type=HISTORY&suggestionId=sony+headphones&requestId=ad797917-16ae-401e-98df-1c79a43d40c3&as-backfill=on&page={page}'

    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(3)  

    soup = BS(driver.page_source, 'html5lib')

    all_containers = soup.find_all('div', {'class': '_4ddWXP'})
    
    for container in all_containers:
        find_url = container.find('a')['href']
        print('find_url:', find_url)
        item_url = 'https://www.flipkart.com' + find_url

        driver.get(item_url)
        time.sleep(3)
        
        item_soup = BS(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
        
        try:
            product_name = item_soup.find('span', {'class': 'B_NuCI'}).text.strip()
            price = item_soup.find('div', {'class': "_30jeq3 _16Jk6d"}).text.strip()

            print('product_name:', product_name)
            print('price:', price)
            print('item_url:', item_url)
            print('---')
            
            row = [product_name, price, item_url]
            all_rows.append(row)
                
        except Exception as ex:
            print('Not Available:', ex)
            print('---')
        
# - after loop -

df = pd.DataFrame(all_rows)

filename = dt.datetime.now().strftime("amazon_data_%d_%b_%y_%I_%M_%p.csv")
df.to_csv(filename)

#filename = dt.datetime.now().strftime("amazon_data_%d_%b_%y_%I_%M_%p.xlsx")
#df.to_excel(filename)
```

Comment: Bro the code worked perfectly for me, Can i do same thing using dictionary?

Comment: old rule: first try, next ask :) You can keep every row as dictionary `row = {'Product Name': product_name, 'Price': price, 'Item URL': item_url}` and append to `all_rows` as before. Or you can create dictionary `all_rows = {'Product Name': [], 'Price': [], 'Item URL': []}` and append to every list separatelly. `all_rows['Product Name'].append(product_name)`, etc. But in all versions I would still convert all to `pandas.DataFrame` which has many useful function and it can be more useful then keeping it in dictionary.

Comment: Thank you so much, Can you tell me how should i Improve my question so that I never lose my reputation. I'm in learning mode and stackoverflow is really helpful. But I've also read if your reputation get bad you cant ask a single ques. So can you let me know how to improve questions, code format for public, Description etc.

Comment: first you should try to use `search` on Stackoverflow (or `Google`) to see if this question wasn't resolve it - question can be downvoted if there is already similar question. People may also downvote it when problem seems to be too trival to ask question - but for you it may not be so trivial and you can't stop downvotes. You have to also remeber that we can't read in your mind and you have to put all details. If you get error then show FULL error. If you run with some data then put example data in code - and you could create minimal working code so we could simply copy it and run it.

Comment: if you tested some solutions then add it (as code or link to other questions) - so will know which methods we don't have to suggest as solution. But always first you should try to debug it - you can at least use `print()` to see values in variable and which code is executed. And you could also add this in question so we could see that you tried to resolve this problem. BTW: if you use `range(1)` then you could add in code as comment `range(1):  # range(1) only for (fast) test` - and this explain why you used so strange value (again: we can't read in your mind)

Comment: I've updated the question as per format, Do you mind removing the downvote for question?